# Having selected data from one datagrid be displayed on another datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to select one customer from a datagrid and then have that customers name be displayed in a list of customers that are being seen that day

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid Name="gridListOfAllCustomers" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="235,26,-740,56" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGridListOfAllCustomers" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Customer}" SelectionChanged="dataGridListOfAllCustomers_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer User Name" Binding="{Binding UserName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding Birthday, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

^ That grid is the one I am selecting data from

```
<Grid Name="gridCustomersOfTheDay" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="10,2,2,42" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGridCustomersToday" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="0"   AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGridCustomersToday_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
    <Button Name="btnEditCustomersToday" Content="Edit List" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Name="btnClearCustomers"  Content="Clear List" Grid.Row="2" Click="btnClearCustomers_Click"/>
 </Grid>
```

^ That Grid should display the data

This is what happens when I click the button for todays Customers

```
private void btnCustomersToday_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnCustomersToday.IsChecked == true)
    {
       dataGridListOfAllCustomers.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
       dataGridCustomersToday.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridListOfAllCustomers.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapse;
        dataGridCustomersToday.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapse;
    }

    ResponseBase<List<CustomerInfo>> allCustomers = Data.DataManager.GetCustomerList("");
    List<CustomerInfo> listOfAllCustomers = allCustomers.Data;
    dataGridListOfAllCustomers.ItemsSource = listOfAllCustomers; //Field
    dataGridCustomersToday.ItemsSource = displayWorkList; //Field
}
```

And lastly this is for the selection change

```
private void  dataGridListOfAllCustomers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{       
    CustomerInfo CustomerForTodayList = (CustomerInfo) dataGridListOfAllCustomers.SelectedItem;
    if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    currentCustomersToday.Add(CustomerForTodayList.UserName);

    String customerID = CustomerForTodayList.UserName;
    StringValue addCustomer = new StringValue(customerID);

    displayWorkList.Add(addCustomer);


}
```

So the issue is I click the customer and I have to change the visibility of the second datagrid in order for User name of the customer to appear. Also there is a lag on the second customer for some reason. As in when I select the second customer I also need to select a third customer in order for them to appear (I still need to click).

I don't even know what could be possible solutions because my understanding of databinding and datagrids is so limited. I have tried reading the documentation and reading tutorials but no one thoroughly explains path and sources as well as how to make a collections and so.

Comment: prefer to use `DataBinding` and `ViewModel` for your scenarios.

Comment: The issue is I do not know how to use either of those and the tutorials online do not give enough background for them to be helpful

Comment: you should have the patience to read and understand try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid)

Comment: A way I have found to make it work is make the source null and then making the source the same again, however I would like to think that there is a more elegant solution

Comment: the way you are doing is good as long as it works. but prefer to understand `MVVM`, `DataBinding ` will be helpful in future.